# Windows: Can the return value of a process running C++ code be accessed if you don't run from command line?

Tags: windows

I know that you can access the return value of the process using the command line or by having one process create and run the other.  However, if I just make an *.exe and double click it, does the return value go anywhere that I can access?  If so, where?  Could I change any settings so that, if my process returns EXIT_FAILURE, Windows will handle things differently than if it returns EXIT_SUCCESS?

Comment: No. The operating system itself does not use this return code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think anything retains the exit value of a process started in that way.  When you double click on a shortcut or executable, Explorer creates the process and then immediately closes the handles because it no longer cares what happens.

You could write a program that calls `OpenProcess` on the process of interest while it's running.  (It would have to have a way to discover the process ID before the process exits.)  OpenProcess will give you a handle to the process.  The program could then wait on that handle.  When the process exits, the program could use the handle to retrieve the status code and do whatever it is you want it to do.